# Force python to display hex as hex

Tags: python, hex

I have a program which makes binary substitutions to a file. As part of this program a regular expression match object is created to match the binary to be substituted. This is in the form:

```
a = re.compile(b"|".join([list_of_hex_to_be_substituted])
```

This object is then printed for debugging purposes. However, when it is printed I encounter the issue that python substitutes some hex values for their ascii equivalents and leaves some alone. In an extreme example this can result in issues like

```
print(b"\x01\x00\x5C\x78\x33\x34")
--> b"\x01\x00\\x34
```

as `5C 78 33 34` in ascii is `\x34`. This is extremely confusing when debugging the script. What I am looking for is a way to simply print the hex as hex (no ascii substiution)

Comment: Would `print(b"\x01\x00\x5C\x78\x33\x34".hex())` suit you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

There is the [`bytes.hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex) method for that:

```
 hex([sep[, bytes_per_sep]])
```

> Return a string object containing two hexadecimal digits for each byte in the instance.

If you want to make the hex string easier to read, you can specify a single character separator *sep* parameter to include in the output. By default, this separator will be included between each byte. A second optional *bytes_per_sep* parameter controls the spacing. Positive values calculate the separator position from the right, negative values from the left.

> **NOTE**: The optional parameters are present since version `3.8` and the method is introduced in version `3.5`

### Examples

1. Without parameters

Here is some examples without parameters, notice that the default value for *sep* is an empty string(e.g. `''`, `""`)

```
>>> b'\xf0\xf1\xf2'.hex()
'f0f1f2'
```

2. using the *sep* and the *bytes_per_sep* parameters

Here are some examples using both optional parameters if you have any doubt on how these work, they should be clear with this example:

```
>>> value = b"\x01\x00\x5C\x78\x33\x34"
>>> value.hex(' ',1)
'01 00 5c 78 33 34'
>>> value.hex(" ",2)
'0100 5c78 3334'
```